# Slow communication between Wemos and Raspberry via WiFi

Tags: python, c++, sockets, communication, esp8266

I have got [PTZ controller](https://www.google.com/search?q=ptz%20controller&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdhrO0rYbnAhVMi1wKHTWmAPgQ_AUoAXoECAsQAw), Wemos D1 Mini (based on ESP8266-12F) and Raspberry and I want read data from PTZ using Wemos and send it via wifi to Raspberry. This is my code on RPi:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
# host = socket.gethostname()
host = '192.168.0.26'
port = 9999
s.connect((host, port))

try:
    while True:
        response1 = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print(response1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    s.close()
```

And my code on Wemos:

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"

int msg = 0;
String str = String(0,HEX);
bool startReading = false;
String command = "";

const char *ssid = "MyName";
const char *password = "MyPassword";

WiFiServer wifiServer(9999);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

  for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
      Serial.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
      Serial.flush();
      delay(1000);
  } 
  delay(1000);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting..");
  }

  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi. IP:");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  wifiServer.begin();
}

void loop() {

  WiFiClient client = wifiServer.available();

  if (client) {

    while (client.connected()) {

      msg = Serial.read();
      if (msg != -1) {
        command = String(msg,HEX);
        client.print(command);
      }
      delay(1);
    }

    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");

  }
}
```

Everything work fine, reaading data from PTZ is immediate but sending data to RPi is slow, I can see significant delay. Reducing the distance from the router does not improve the situation. I tried use `#include <WebSocketsServer.h>` but this libary is even worse. My question is how I can increase communication speed? Will putting the server on rpi instead of wemos help? Are there any more suitable libraries that I could use?

Comment: I could be off base here, but code looks fine. It sounds like your bottle neck is from the hardware. I have zero experience with a Wemos D1 Mini, but it's not the most powerful device out there with a clock speed of 80MHz/160MHz.

Comment: you send the data over WiFi in one or a few bytes small packets. use some buffering. and remove the delay

Comment: I send many small packets but i can't chege this. I need continuous data transmission because this data is used to control a mobile vehicle. Buffering don't solve my problems.

Comment: so you want to send one byte wrappen in TCP packet, encrypted and wrapped for WiFi transport every millisecond?

Comment: Not every milisecond, approximately every 50 ms. What do you suggest? Change wifi for example on bluetooth?